Making sense of 障害ー他者をも、踏破する強さー
I am uncertain how this sentence is structured in the below panel:

それが持つべき資質は自己犠牲? それとも、目的のために、障害ー他者をも、踏破する強さー

In the bold part, the use of ー is throwing me off. I wonder if it is supposed to be understood as something like 障害と他者をも踏破する強さ, a strength that can overcome obstacles and other people.

(Source: she is beautiful ch. 49)

The dash between 障害 and 他者 seems to be used as an apposition marker (i.e., "障害 is 他者", not "障害 and 他者"). The other dashes are simple ellipses (equivalent of …). So it's like this:

それ(=新人類)が持つべき資質は自己犠牲？ それとも目的のために障害[—]{すなわち}他者をも踏破する強さ？
Should they have the virtue of self-sacrifice? Or should they have the strength to conquer even other people as "obstacles" for their aims?

